# Add a 3D model: what types of file are supported? And where to host the 3D file?

Tags: 3d, mapbox, gltf

From here > https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/, I found that the 3D model in the example is loaded from 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf'.

1. I wonder what types of file are supported except .gltf? Can I load model from Revit, Sketchup, AchiCAD, etc?
2. And where can I hosted the 3D file? Can I load it from dropbox, google drive, etc?

Comment: This question may be too open-ended for Stack Overflow — please try to ask one question, with a verifiable answer. Questions asking for recommended hosting services are likely to be a matter of opinion. The example you link to uses three.js, so you can refer to https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models for suggestions on formats. For hosting, a search for "static hosting services" will give you a lot of options.

Answer (score 2):

[Three js allows you to load many different formats](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models), including Collada (.dae), FBX (.fbx), OBJ/MTL, 3MF, [and more](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/jsm/loaders). You'll need to replace the loader script by the one you want to load.

The files could be hosted in a different domain to the page being executed, but most probably you'll need to deal with CORS-enabled domains.

If you are going to play hard with Mapbox and Three js, I'd recommend you to check [Threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) out, a plugin to simplify the interaction between both with only a few lines of code, indeed the three.js loader sample will be reduced to only these lines.

```js
map.on('style.load', function () {
    map.addLayer({
        id: 'custom_layer',
        type: 'custom',
        renderingMode: '3d',
        onAdd: function (map, mbxContext) {
            window.tb = new Threebox(
                map,
                mbxContext,
                { defaultLights: true }
            );

            let options = {
                type: 'gltf', //'gltf'/'mtl'
                obj: './models/radar/34M_17.gltf', //model url
                    units: 'meters', 
                    scale: 1,
                    rotation: { x: 90, y: 180, z: 0 }, //default rotation
                    anchor: 'center'
            }
            tb.loadObj(options, function (model) {
                model.setCoords(origin);
                tb.add(model);
            });

        },
        render: function (gl, matrix) {
            tb.update();
        }
    });
})
```

Apart from other features such as built-in raycasting, models selection, drag&rotate, drag&move, animations, tooltips & labels on altitude or **sun light shadows** [image: Eiffel tower gif]

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please mark it as **answer accepted**, in that way will also help other users to know it was the right solution